# Wifi signal strength monitoring in ROS fuerte?

Tags: ros, wifi, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Does anyone know if Fuerte actually integrated wireless signal strength support? I personally would like to monitor strengths of various wireless signals and based on that do planning like when to connect to the server.

[This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning/IPC/WiFiNeeds) page suggests that "signal strength" support was added in Fuerte. Also, [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/32390/ros-fuerte-wifi-support/) suggests that [wpa_supplicant_node](http://ros.org/wiki/wpa_supplicant) can be used for signal strength support.

However, [wpa_supplicant_node](http://ros.org/wiki/wpa_supplicant) is undocumented and seems to be only dealing with WPA  (i.e. security)side of the wireless signals based on the source code. It does not give the ability to query wireless signals and their strengths as I wish.

Is there any other node in Fuerte that can help me monitor the wireless signal strengths?  Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36453/wifi-signal-strength-monitoring-in-ros-fuerte?/) by [ulzi.otgonbaatar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2598/ulzi.otgonbaatar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I went from a fresh Fuerte install, and installed the [linux_networking](http://ros.org/wiki/linux_networking) stack.  Using the new `rosws`, this is pretty straightforward:

```
roslocate info linux_networking | rosws merge -
rosws update
```

I then installed the dependencies and compiled the `wpa_supplicant_node`:

```
rosdep install wpa_supplicant_node
rosmake wpa_supplicant_node
```

Once this is all set up, you can get the node running.  I believe that this has to be done with super user privileges, as that's what `wpa_supplicant` requires.  Someone may know how to do this with regular user privileges.

The node takes the arguments that wpa_supplicant would normally take, so in my case, I did the following:

```
sudo -s
source ~/devel/wireless/setup.bash
rosrun wpa_supplicant_node wpa_supplicant_node -iwlan0 -ctest.conf -Dnl80211 -dd
```

Once running, a `rostopic list` returns the following:

```
/wifi/wlan0/associate/cancel
/wifi/wlan0/associate/feedback
/wifi/wlan0/associate/goal
/wifi/wlan0/associate/result
/wifi/wlan0/associate/status
/wifi/wlan0/association_state
/wifi/wlan0/frequency_list
/wifi/wlan0/network_list
/wifi/wlan0/scan/cancel
/wifi/wlan0/scan/feedback
/wifi/wlan0/scan/goal
/wifi/wlan0/scan/result
/wifi/wlan0/scan/status
/wifi/wlan0/scan_results
/wpa_supplicant/parameter_descriptions
/wpa_supplicant/parameter_updates
```

If you simply want network signal strength, I would suggest using the `/*/scan_results` topic, which returns the following:

```
∫ rostopic echo /wifi/wlan0/scan_results
success: True
bss: 
  - 
    stamp: 
      secs: 1339715209
      nsecs: 925256105
    ssid: Avocado
    bssid: [0, 127, 40, 49, 227, 125]
    frequency: 2437
    beacon_interval: 100
    capabilities: 1073
    quality: 0
    noise: 0
    level: -46
    wpa: 
      key_mgmt: ['wpa-psk']
      group: ['tkip']
      pairwise: ['tkip', 'ccmp']
    rsn: 
      key_mgmt: ['wpa-psk']
      group: ['tkip']
      pairwise: ['tkip', 'ccmp']
  - 
    stamp: 
      secs: 1339715208
      nsecs: 921288442
    ssid: ZEO32
    bssid: [0, 24, 1, 236, 26, 48]
    frequency: 2412
    beacon_interval: 100
    capabilities: 1329
    quality: 0
    noise: 0
    level: -86
    wpa: 
      key_mgmt: []
      group: []
      pairwise: []
    rsn: 
      key_mgmt: []
      group: []
      pairwise: []
---
```

This shows the (rather sparse) wifi networks in my apartment.  You can also make calls through the [Actionlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib) interface to the node as well.

Hope this helps you out.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ulzi.otgonbaatar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2598/ulzi.otgonbaatar/) on 2012-06-15**:
Thanks a lot. I really helps.